# How can I calculate the expected flow rate from a model of a pump

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I am doing this problem for practice and I am stuck and do not know how to proceed. The question is a pump with diameter of 40 cm is expected to deliver 1.5 $\frac{m^3}{s}$ of water at gauge pressure of 400 kPa, where the pressure coefficient is $$\frac{p-p_{atm}}{\rho U^2}$$ to test the pump a model of diameter 8 cm has been considered. Using a dynamical similarity based on the Reynolds number, calculate the expected flow rate of the model. What is the expected pressure rise for this model?
Where I am stuck to is how I would make a reynolds number based model with this and how that would help me calculate the flow rate, and I am assuming that the pressure rise would come from this model directly. Any help would be appreciated